# Can't add frames in Photoshop CC 2018

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, creative-cloud

I'm trying to animate in Photoshop CC 2018 and I can't get a frame to show up. The menu bar at the bottom won't show up and I keep trying to add frames, but with not option available.

[image: Animating in Photoshop]

[image: Timeline Image]

My timeline will show, but nothing seems to allow me to add my layers to the frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can add frame by doing this

- click "**Create Frame Animation**". By Clicking this this type of timeline appearance .

[image]

- you have to **create a new layer for each frame.** you can Crate new frame by clicking on Red highlighted icon.

[image]